# How can I get category page hyperlinks of my Jekyll website hosted on GitHub working?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

For a [Jeykll website](https://fkromer.github.io/design-pattern-references/) hosted on GitHub I created a custom solution (no Jeykll plugin) to display all post links of a category on a page *****. I use the [setup of GitHub pages for local Jekyll builds](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/) and build with `bundle exec jekyll serve` locally. If visit `http://127.0.0.1:4000` and push one of the hyper-link buttons *Embedded*, *Hardware* or *Software* in the left side-bar below *Pattern Categories* the post links are shown like expected.

However if I visit the website hosted on GitHub I get an "404 File not found" error. From the past I can remember that this could relate to a different handling of Jekylls permalinks in local and GitHub Pages builds. But I cannot remember in detail.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

*** Sitenote:** Right now instead of listing only the post links for a single category the post links of all categories are listed section wise. But that does not matter w.r.t. to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the website isn't located at the root level, so you need to use in `_config.yml` the base url:

```
baseurl: /design-pattern-references
```

Then make use of that setting generating full paths, e.g.: in `_layouts/index.html`

```
 <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

Comment: Will local builds still work with this solution? Or how can I manage the differences if required to do so?

Comment: @thinwybk yes it works locally also. You can access the website with jekyll serve at localhost:4000/design-pattern-references

Comment: With '| absolute_url' it did not work for me in the local build. But you guided me [into the right direction](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The hyperlinks of *Embedded*, *Hardware* and *Software* on the left side of the landing page was not correct. The site url was showing up in the hyperlink twice in front of the baseurl or something like that...

Comment: It was probably because that hyperlink on the left side wasn't using absolute_url but prepending the url or baseurl.